# Displaying a Youtube video within an AIR Android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, video, youtube, air

I'm trying to display a Youtube video within an AIR Android app.

Usually, I call the Youtube API player like this (barebones only):

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
player = loader.content;
player.loadVideoById("12345678901",0);
```

I don't know why, but this method doesn't work anymore.
Here's what happens on the ANDROID device (I compiled using AIR v18):
The video seems to be buffering for a few seconds, then the movieClip holding the API player becomes transparent, no video is displayed.
The sound of the video is playing though.

Meanwhile, on the ADL, the video shows up as it should.

I'm using Android 5, the Youtube Video is on public status, and I already re-tried after uninstalling the Android app (but does it clear the cache?).

Does anybody has a clue on what's going on?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could just load the iframe url in a `StageWebView`.  Google may have dropped support for AS3

Comment: Google officially says that the YouTube ActionScript 3.0 Player API has been DEPRECATED: https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference?hl=en

(PS: DEPRECATED doesn't mean necessarely Dropped).

So I tried the StageWebView + iFrame solution as described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

The results are still not good: Video Thumbnail is displayed, but when the play button is hit, the buffering circles are displayed and I get stuck right there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is as follows:

I added this simple line in my app descriptor:

```
<manifest>
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
</manifest> ]]>
```